# Firebase Functions trigger Analytics by appVersion or session_start?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

My app has users who downloaded old apk outside Play Store and are using unlicensed old versions that did not have security checks.

I need the firebase to identify and block all application accesses from versions lower than a given version.

A lot of research, and some blocking I got through **realtime-database rules**, but it is not effective when users downgrade.

My hope is to get through **Firebase Functions** to create a trigger in **Analytics** that monitors the version of the application in session_start or something similar so that if it is an old version, block the realtime-database by rules.

Is it possible to create a **firebase function** triggered by **analytics** **appVersion** or **session_start**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Analytics triggers only work for events that you've defined as conversation events.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events):

> Only events marked as conversion events are currently supported by
>   Cloud Functions. You can specify which events are conversion events in
>   the Events tab of the Firebase console Analytics pane.

The only default events that are also conversion events are documented [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522?hl=en#enable) (first_open, in_app_purchase, and ecommerce_purchase).

Comment: Understood, but what about https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.analytics.AppInfo?hl=pt-br#appVersion is it possible to get this information with an trigger event?

Comment: Sure, if the event is a conversion event.  In your case, it is not, so your function will not trigger.